# Call a tabbar's view method at launch

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to do the following:
I've a few viewControllers in a tabBarController.
At launch, the tabBarController (and obviously anything in it) is hidden behind a "splashScreenView" called from the appDelegate.

The splashScreenView has a UIActivityIndicator and remain visible while the app is getting data from a webserver.

To keep things simple, I'd like each view of the tabBarController to manage their own data.
I'm using the "viewDidLoad" method to get those data.

The question is: How can I trigger the viewDidLoad method of each tabBarController's views from the appDelegate's appDidFinishLaunching?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is load the tab bar just as you would normally, but set `self.tabBarController.view.hidden` to `YES`. That way, you can do `addSubview` for you splashscreen and it appears to be the only view there.

When the splash screen is dismissed, just change the hidden value to `NO` and if desired, add an animation to make it fade in, or make the splash screen fade out.

While the splash screen is in place, just run `viewDidLoad` for each tab bar view controller (while running the activity monitor). Once done, dismiss the activity monitor while keeping the splash screen in place, or dismissing that too based on what your goal is. Does this help?

Comment: My splashScreen is already fully fonctionnal... with fade out etc.
The problem now is how to call viewDidLoad for the same instance asthe tabBar's ?

Comment: I hacked it with [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];... if you have something less trashy... :)

Comment: I'm confused at that. You want to call `viewDidLoad` for each of the tab bar's view controllers, yeah? Just call them by creating instances of each one in your app delegate and using those instances (so, call `viewDidLoad` on `tabBarViewController1` for example). Just do it for all them and you should be set.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that second comment. I like it :) not too trashy :) but try my way if possible for how you set it up. Might work better in the end.

Comment: That's what I tried with the method given by Thomas K in the previous reply... But when I tap on the tabBar's tab corrsponding to tabBarViewController1, the viewDidLoad method gets re-invoked...

Comment: Hmm. I would have to see your code to delve deeper into this. Sorry. It doesn't make sense unless you're not properly loading it the first time (when the app loads).

Comment: in appDidFinishLaunching, I have:
` ViewController1 *foo = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    [foo viewDidLoad];`
In console, I can see that the viewDidLoad works correctly, but if after that, I call the same foo by taping the corresponding tab, the viewDidLoad method is re-invoked. Get it? :)

Comment: Odd. I have no idea why that's happening. I would need to see the code to help more

Comment: I found this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml
The explain how to handle data models... I'll try this :) Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yep. No problem. Sorry I wasn't much of a help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think you would be better of using a model for the data operations, you could do this:

```
ViewController1 *foo = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    [foo viewDidLoad];

ViewController2 *bar = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [bar viewDidLoad];
```

Also, with this method, I think you'd be better of putting de data operation's logic in a separate method and call that from your app delegate.

Comment: I'm pretty new to MVC and I'm still stuck with the "M" part... could you explain how to deal with data models?

Comment: Well basically it sounds like you're getting some data from an API, you want to show. What I'd do is make a separate class for all the API calls and a class that reads/writes data from/to a local SQLite DB. In that way you can conveniently make calls from anywhere at anytime.

Comment: The method you gave me above creates a second instance of my view... when I tap on the corresponding tab, the viewDidLoad method gets re-invoked.

Comment: I'll have a look to your API thing...
For now, do you now how to solve my previous comment's issue?

Comment: I hacked it with [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];... if you have something less trashy... :)